# SQL Server : return list real week of startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I'm in trouble with a hard case. How can I get every real weeks base on `startdate` and `enddate`?

Example:

```
@startdate datetime = '2021-05-01',
@enddate datetime = '2021-05-31'
```

Expected result:

```
|datefrom|   ~   |dateto|
2021-05-01      2021-05-02
2021-05-03      2021-05-09
2021-05-10      2021-05-16
2021-05-17      2021-05-23
2021-05-24      2021-05-30
2021-05-31      2021-05-31
```

Comment: `DATEPART(weekday, 'yyyy/mm/dd')` will give you a number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday). You can use this to calculate the calendar weeks.

Answer (score 1):

you need recursice cte :

```
declare @startdate date ='2021-05-15',
        @enddate date ='2021-06-15'


;with cte as ( 
Select 
    @startdate weekstart
    , DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startdate), CAST(@startdate AS DATE)) weekend
union all 
select 
    DATEADD(day , 1 , weekend) 
    , case when DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day , 1 , weekend)), CAST(DATEADD(day , 1 , weekend) AS DATE))  >= @enddate then @enddate 
    else DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(day , 1 , weekend)), CAST(DATEADD(day , 1 , weekend) AS DATE)) end weekend
from cte 
where DATEADD(day , 1 , weekend) <= @enddate
)

select * from cte
```

> ```
> weekstart  | weekend   
> :--------- | :---------
> 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-02
> 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-09
> 2021-05-10 | 2021-05-16
> 2021-05-17 | 2021-05-23
> 2021-05-24 | 2021-05-30
> 2021-05-31 | 2021-05-31
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dd6c94ae433a0e8879e9c4c664afdf14)*

Note : I used `date` as date type to simplify , but there should be no issue working with datetime , just change casting to datetime everywhere in query